# How to Create a GIT repository for the project on PHPStorm

Tags: git, laravel, repository, phpstorm

I have been working on a Laravel Project. I dont have any version control in my project. I want turn this project into a repository so I can send add another developper to my project. I tried the VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Create GIT REpository.

But all the times I'm unable to commit new changes or update the Project.

I'm New to this version controlling and repositories. Please help me add a version controlling to my project and convert it to a team development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to install Git on your system. PhpStorm is only a IDE and it will help you to issue the various GIT commands by GUI, but it relies on the underlying git process. So, make sure to install and configure GIT properly on your machine

Once you have Git up and working, you have to set in PHPStorm the path of your git executable:

```
Setting -> Version Control -> GIT -> Path to git executable
```

At this point PhpStorm knows how to use GIT and you can add your project to version control:

```
VCS -> enable version control integration -> GIT
```

Now you have created a repository for your project, but it's still empty: you have to add your project's files to it: open the tool window `changes`, select all of your files that you want to be versioned under `unversioned files` and click on `Add to VCS`

Now all of your files are in your repository and you can make the firs commit

Comment: @php_beginner : if it was useful, please accept the answer checking the V on the left of the answer